# How To Extract Json Data Filed With RestApi?

Tags: java, api, rest-assured, jsonpath, jsonparser

i make a post to an api with rest assured. and than i try to make sure expected data from responsed data ,
but i got some errors like this -> "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The parameter "data" was used but not defined. Define parameters using the JsonPath.params(...) function"

---

my code:

```
String payload_data = "{" +
                "\"Time\":1638057600, " +
                "\"exampleType\":example, " +
                "\"Id\":[2]}";

    RestAssured.defaultParser = Parser.JSON;
    given().
            contentType(ContentType.JSON).
            body(payload_data).
            when().
            post(api_url).
            then().
            statusCode(200).
            body("data.examples.2.exampleData", equalTo("33"));
}
```

---

my json data

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "examples": {
            "2": {
                "ex_data": 0,
                "exampleData": 33,
                "data_ex": 0,
            }
      }
}
```

Comment: use online tools like https://jsonlint.com/ to validate your JSON

Answer (score 1):

First, I tested path `"data.examples.2.exampleData"` with your json, it works fine. No problem.

You made some mistakes here.

1. Your payload is invalid json.

```
{
  "Time": 1638057600,
  "exampleType": example, //it must be number or String with double quote
  "Id": [
    2
  ]
}
```

2. You are comparing 2 things with different data types.

`"data.examples.2.exampleData"` --> int 33

`equalTo("33")` --> String "33"

Fix: `body("data.examples.2.exampleData", equalTo(33));`